# Laravel Envoy This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, laravel-envoy

I have a laravel 5.7 project in which I would like to deploy to the server with laravel envoy. If I run

`envoy run deploy`

I get the following error:

> [✗] This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.

I tried running this from cygwin, git bash and cmd and all gave the same result. I can login with ssh to my server so that's setup correctly. Also if I run the following:

```
envoy ssh
```

it logs me into the server. We tried it from another Windows 10 machine and it works just nicely. So it probably has to do something with my setup although we can't figure out why?

**Additional information:**

```
Windows 10
PHP 7.2.11
Laravel Envoy 1.5.0 (is installed globally)
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019
```

Envoy.blade.php

```
@servers(['web' => 'user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'])

@task('deploy', ['on' => 'web'])
    cd domains/domain.com/
    git pull origin master
@endtask
```

Answer (score 0):

After switching from this php version

```
PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2018 02:04:07) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

to this version:

```
PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Apr 10 2018 18:09:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Envoy suddenly works

Comment: I have the same problem, other than changing the version, what else could've been the cause? Missing PHP extensions?

Comment: I really have no idea. I thought it had something to do with the NTS(non-thread safe) but after installing a different version of 7.2 (NTS) I ran into the same error again. So eventually my solution was to install php version in cygwin.